# InvalidArgumentError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 16

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to make an image classifier CNN using tensoflow. I am trying to load the dataset using a `ImageDataGenerator`. Like this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)

IMAGE_DIMS = (200,200)
train_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    TRAIN_DIR,
    target_size=IMAGE_DIMS,
    batch_size=80,
    class_mode="categorical",
    shuffle=True
)
```

This is what my Network looks like:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv2D(16,(3,3), input_shape=(200,200,1), activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3), activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=64, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=16, activation="softmax")
])

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
```

When I try to fit the model to the dataset by doing:

```
model.fit(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=4,
    epochs=2
)
```

I am getting this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 16
```

I am relatively new to TensorFlow, and I have no idea what is going wrong here. I have tried it with different datasets, different optimizers, different numbers of layers, different loss functions, nothing worked.

What is going wrong? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How many classes do you have in your dataset? Note that you can't use `class_mode="categorical"` and `loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'` together.

Comment: @Lescurel 16 classes

Comment: I can't be certain, but when you say `I have tried it with different datasets, different optimizers, different numbers of layers, different loss functions, nothing worked`, did you get consistently the same error message? Also, please add the full python Traceback when you are asking a python related question, it's helpful to know where your code failed.

Comment: I don't get the same error but there is no trace back either

Answer (score 0):

As you have used `softmax` activation in the output layer with 16 nodes, I assume you have 16 mutually exclusive classes. Your `y` data then should only be an a list of 16 zeros and ones, not integer of numbers 0 to 15 - which would be what the `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` loss function expects.

Try setting the loss function to `categorical_crossentropy` to accommodate, **or** set the `class_mode` of the ImageDataGenerator to 'sparse' as well!